# How do you ignore Joomla Form Field SQL limit

Tags: joomla, joomla3.3

When you use the standard Joomla Form Field SQL there's a limit to the number of entries it can return (somewhere around 5000, I found).  I found this out when I queried a select list that had 30k+ entries.  It wouldn't work unless I added a limit 0, 5000 max.

Is creating a custom form field the only solution or is there some other way to stop this from happening?  Also, does anyone know where and why this limit exists?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330536/1985305

The limit wasn't being imposed by Joomla, it was a browser Limit.  Chrome/Firefox have a maximum of 10k options in select boxes.  I was using two with 4k and ~5k each and maxing it out, shoot.

EDIT:

Nope, just kidding.  Did it again a different way and managed to get 26k out, but I can't reach my 34k to fit all my items.

No longer using Joomla form field, but am using Joomla DB methods.  Any ideas?