# Maximum data that can be loaded in the dropdown control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having some 90,000 records in table and I want to load those records in dropdown. But when I run the application and when I click on dropdown control it expands and shrinks on its own. But when I take only top 10 records of table, dropdown control loads properly with data. What is the maximum limit for dropdown to hold data? Is it brower dependent? Are there any controls for loading huge amount of data in controls other than dropdown?

Comment: why you need all 90k records ? instead use AutoSuggest Textbox with top 30 or 40 elements

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried to use autolist i.e textbox combined with listbox. It is working but once we enter a letter in textbox then either we have to press Tab key or we have click outside the textbox then only the suggestions are being displayed in listbox. But its not that user friendly. Can we use Autosuggest textbox for webforms?

Comment: @shipla yes same as google search textbox

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit on maximum items, see related question [Is there a max number of options (values) in HTML drop down control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763/is-there-a-max-number-of-options-values-in-html-drop-down-control)

however you shouldn't use dropdown for more than 20 items instead try https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you for the response. With autocomplete it's working good.