# Multiselect Dropdown Box limit in option

Tags: php, html

I have one Multiselect box in html. I have to total 2500 Options in Selectbox I am try to post all option using html form but only the 1000 option will post i have already increase "post_max_size" ie. 25000M , "upload_max_filesize" ie.24998M  and "memory_limit" ie. 25000M is their any limit for post options.

Html Code is mention as below.

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
<select name="companylist[]" style="width:300px;height:80px" multiple="multiple">
<?php 
  foreach($options as $key => $val){
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $val;?>"><?php echo $val;?></option>
  <?php
 }
 ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42763/is-there-a-max-number-of-options-values-in-html-drop-down-control

Comment: I'm just curious, of those 2500 options, how many is a person likely to select at any one time?

Comment: I am more curious about the user that is going to walk through 2500 items in a dropdown! I would bet they will go somewhere else more often than bothering to look past about 40 options

Comment: Select box contain 2500 option and select box is multiselected so i have take care of it  all values are post properly. but under the above link answer is properly defined.