# getValues from Google Sheet to html <select>

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm rather new to Google Scripts and HTML and I've managed to put together something from what I could gathered on other posts, but I've hit a wall when trying to automatically populate an html dropdown menu from a Google Sheet workbook.

The aim is to pop up a sidebar on a Google Sheet that contains a dropdown menu based on data from that same Google Sheet.

Below the codes & additional context.

**GOOGLE SCRIPT**

```js
function mediaplanAdminSidebar() {
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mediaplan').setTitle('HELP');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget)
  SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true)
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <style>span{font-size: 34px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: normal;font-style: normal;font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
  <style>text{font-size: 24px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: normal;font-style: normal;font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
  <style>p{font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: normal;font-style: normal;font-family: sans-serif;}</style>
  <style>label{font-size: 14px;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: normal;font-style: normal;font-family: sans-serif;}</style>

  <br/><span>Paid Social</span>
  <br/><text>Media planner</text>
  <p>Through this menu you will be able to produce a slide deck containing basic media buying info as well as the forecast for a campaign of your choice.</p>
  
<label>Select your campaign:</label></br>

<div>
    <select>
      <option>
        <script>
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName('[PAID] #1-Activity tracker');
          var myrange = sheet.getRange(7,6,1000);
          var campnames = myrange.getValues();
          campnames[1];
        </script>
      </option>
  </select>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Further context:

- This might look horribly wrong to most of you, but I'm struggling to grasp the basics of it, and I am failing to understand how to make these two pieces of code talk to each other.
- I have tried a couple different ways without success. The above is the last I've got.
- That given range (7,6,10000) in that particular sheet has data.
- This is what it looks like (see below). Note the dropdown menu is empty.

[image: sidebar]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427670/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that you are trying to run Google Apps Script at the Javascript side. I think that this is the reason for your issue. And also, when `campnames[1];` is output, the 2nd element of the array `campnames` is used. I thought that this might be your 2nd issue.

If you want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet on the Google Apps Script side and show the values in the dropdown list of the HTML side, how about the following modification?

#### HTML side:

##### From:

```
<div>
    <select>
      <option>
        <script>
          var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName('[PAID] #1-Activity tracker');
          var myrange = sheet.getRange(7,6,1000);
          var campnames = myrange.getValues();
          campnames[1];
        </script>
      </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

##### To:

```
<div><select><?!= data ?></select></div>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

##### From:

```
function mediaplanAdminSidebar() {
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mediaplan').setTitle('HELP');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget)
  SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true)
}
```

##### To:

```
function mediaplanAdminSidebar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName('[PAID] #1-Activity tracker');
  var myrange = sheet.getRange(7, 6, 1000);
  var campnames = myrange.getValues();
  var widget = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mediaplan');
  widget.data = campnames.reduce((s, [e]) => s += `<option value="${e}">${e}<\/option>\n`, "");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget.evaluate().setTitle('HELP'));
}
```

#### Note:

- About the maximum number of options, I thought that this thread might be useful. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42763/7108653)

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: That worked like a charm. I understand now the dropdown menu setup happens on GS, not in HTML like I was trying. Then HTML only pulls the dynamic setup as defined in the GS code. Many thanks!

Comment: @A. Prats Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. The reason that I proposed the above modification is as follows. Of course, `option` tag can be directly put to HTML by sending the values from Spreadsheet to HTML and processing it with `evaluate()`. But from your question, I'm worried that the values might be large and the process cost will be a bit high. So, I proposed to create the tags of `option` and directly put them to the template HTML.